# Foreign Key - Dataannotation

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have been searching for a solution for nearly 4 hours now and cannot find a solution to this.

I have 2 entites where I want to setup a foreign key using dataannotations, the trouble (I think) is with the base entity.

```
public class BaseEntity
{ 
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    [Key]
    public virtual int ID { get; set; }
        ...
}


public class Person : BaseEntity
{
    public string FirtName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }

    public int? PersonAddressID { get; set; }
    public virtual PersonAddress PersonAddress { get; set; }

    public int? MainPersonID { get; set; }
    public virtual Person MainPerson { get; set; }

    public virtual HashSet<Projects.Project> ManagingProjects { get; set; }
    public virtual HashSet<Projects.Project> AdministratingProjects { get; set; }
    public virtual HashSet<Person> Dependants { get; set; }
    ...
}

public class PersonAddress : BaseEntity
{
    public int PersonID { get; set; }
    public virtual Person Person { get; set; }

    public string Street { get; set; }
    public string Town { get; set; }    
    ....
}
```

I tried overriding the base Id and added[Foreignkey("Person")], but still nothing. I tried a couple of approaches and get various errors.

I also tried something like the following with no luck

```
 [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
        [Key]
        [Column(Order = 1)]
        public override int ID { get; set; }

        [Key, Column(Order = 2), ForeignKey("Person")]
        public int PersonID { get; set; }
```

I am trying to figure out how EF does its foreign keys, but I am still stuck on the first one between person and address with a 1 to 1, or 1 to 0 relationship.

Comment: The relationship between person and address is normally one to many. Which means a person can have multiple addresses. (ex: mail, office, home etc).

Comment: Hello Kosala, I do have one to many relationships for lists, this PersonAddress is for as single record 1-to-1. I am using this a sample to get my head around EF relationships for 1-to-1 or 1-to-0

Comment: If you add "Person" as an attribute to "PersonAddress" you will have a cyclic reference like issue. For an example when you load a person object you will have to load PersonAddress (person can exist without an address too). Then, when you load PersonAddress you will need Person to be loaded again inside PersonAddress.. because it cannot be nullable. So your option is to have PersonId in PersonAddress instead of Person.

Comment: I would reconsider my entities and their definitions, inheriting `PersonAddress` from `BaseEntity` may not be a good option

Comment: @KosalaW There is currently both PersonID and Person, are you suggesting not have Person at all?

Comment: @erkaner Hello erkaner, the BaseEntity is part of a extra functionality as well as part of generics. It works fine for one to many and many to many, complex types etc. Its one to one/zero where there is problems

Comment: Yes. Remove Person from PersonAddress and just have PersonId. Otherwise you will have issues when you want to load a full Person object.

Comment: @KosalaW I am not 100% sure I understand what to do with your suggestion. But simply removing the Person and adding the Foreignkey("Person") to the PersonID gives and error. without the Foreign key attribute, the sql relationship does not work as intended.

Comment: Try below code. It should work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was not happy changing the BaseEntity, since I would lose other functionality such as disconnected entity tracking, as well as losing the ID property would limit generics too much for me. But I knew there had to be away and ended up with the following.

```
public class Person : BaseEntity
{
    public string FirtName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }

    public virtual PersonAddress Address { get; set; }
    ...
}

public class PersonAddress : BaseEntity
{
    DatabaseGenerated(System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema.DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
    [Key, ForeignKey("Person")]
    public override int ID { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("ID")]
    public virtual Person Person { get; set; }
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how I would define the classes:

```
public class BaseEntity
{ 
      //how about no key defined here  
      //[Key]
      //public virtual int ID { get; set; }

}


public class Person : BaseEntity
{
    public int PersonId { get; set; }

    public string FirtName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }

    public virtual PersonAddress PersonAddress { get; set; }

    public int? MainPersonID { get; set; }
    public virtual Person MainPerson { get; set; }

    public virtual HashSet<Projects.Project> ManagingProjects { get; set; }
    public virtual HashSet<Projects.Project> AdministratingProjects { get; set; }
    public virtual HashSet<Person> Dependants { get; set; }
}

public class PersonAddress: BaseEntity
{
    [Key, ForeignKey("Person")]    
    public int PersonID { get; set; }
    public virtual Person Person { get; set; }

    public string Street { get; set; }
    public string Town { get; set; }    

}
```

Comment: Thanks. This does help, and confirms there is a problem with using a base, however, I am losing the extra functionality from the base

Comment: you mean `PersonAddress` class losing the functionality?

Comment: yes, PersonAddress loses the additional BaseEntity functionality.

Comment: can you give specific examples? Like what functionality? with straight thinking, actually PersonAddress and Person classes should not inherit from the same base class? I mean their purposes and meanings are different.

Comment: while its true they are different in end purpose, they are still entities. One of the functionalities for example is keeping track of changes or status of an entity in a disconnected scenario. Others will be adding meta data to an entity such as user info, logging etc.

Comment: I updated the code, can you please have a look and try if it works?

Answer (score 0):

Try this one..

```
public class Person 
 {
   public int PersonID { get; set; }
   public string FirtName { get; set; }
   public string LastName { get; set; }

   public virtual PersonAddress PersonAddress { get; set; }
 }

 public class PersonAddress
 {
    [Key, ForeignKey("Person")]    
    public int PersonID { get; set; }   

    public string Street { get; set; }
    public string Town { get; set; }    

    public virtual Person Person { get; set; }
 }

 protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
 {
    // Configure PersonId as PK for PersonAddress
    modelBuilder.Entity<PersonAddress>()
    .HasKey(e => e.PersonId);

   // Configure PersonId as FK for PersonAddress
     modelBuilder.Entity<Person>()
            .HasOptional(s => s.PersonAddress) // Mark PersonAddress is           optional for Person
            .WithRequired(ad => ad.Person); // Create inverse relationship

 }
```